# Python3:ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.7/cv2/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_Type

Tags: python3, opencv

I have installed opencv2 with 'pip3 install opencv' command. After that, I've opened the python3 terminal from 'python3' command. Then typed import cv2 to test installation. Command-line gave me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.7/cv2/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_Type
```

Can I fix this.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need to have it installed through `pip3`, you can uninstall the `opencv` module you installed, then reinstall it through the Ubuntu package `python3-opencv`.

To reverse the effect of `pip3 install opencv`:

```
pip3 uninstall opencv
```

Or if you had actually run `pip3 install opencv` as root (perhaps with `sudo`), then run:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall opencv
```

Then, to install the `opencv` module for Python 3 using Ubuntu's package manager:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Comment: but it doesn't fixed my bug